# Breakpoints not being hit in Visual Studio 2022 for Mac

Tags: c#, .net, macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

So I just started using Visual Studio 2022 on a Mac and I'm having trouble getting my breakpoints to be hit.

I set the breakpoint just as I would if I was using VS for windows but when I run the app in debug mode it is not being hit.

They are by default shown as hollow circles, meaning they might be disabled? But they are shown as enabled when I right-click on them.

[Hollow breakpoint image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzjCd.png)

I've searched everywhere online but can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am also seeing the hollow circle when I set a breakpoint and the breakpoint is never hit.

Answer (score 2):

If that doesn't work just make sure you're not in release. You will not get access to all of the tools if that is the case.

by "that" I mean the answer from JFBloom22

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue in Visual Studio Mac 2022. Enabling **`Fast Deployment`** in android project solved the issue.